# Having difficulty controlling webview from other activities/classes

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

As it stands right now, In my app I am writing, I have a navigation drawer via `NavigationDrawerFragment` with a `RecyclerView` populated via an adapter in another class, and a `WebView` in my `MainActivity`. I'm at a point where I've got click handling from my `RecyclerView`'s adapter and what I want to do is load different content into the `WebView` in the `MainActivity` upon click of a `RecyclerView` item in the navigation drawer. I managed to implement a way to do this with Intents and `putExtra()` but it involved re-launching the MainActivity which felt really clunky and also really tore down the seamless UX that I've intended from the start.

I was thinking that maybe I could have the `WebView` as a `Fragment` and inflate it in the `MainActivity` and maybe this would allow me to control it from the `RecyclerView` adapter? I'm pretty new to Android and Java, and I've been following examples up to this point so I don't really know what will accomplish what, and I'd like to find out for when I am able to get back to my proper coding environment. My laptop isn't the best for it because it takes so long to compile and run.

I suppose what I'm asking is if this idea of mine would be the right way to go, and if not, what would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragment` should be sufficient:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getName();
    public WebView mWebView;

    ...  

    public void updateWebView(String url) {
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

You can always find `Fragments` by tag (or id):

```
get[Support]FragmentManager().findFragmentById(int id);
get[Support]FragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String tag);
```

and invoke methods:

```
WebViewFragment webViewFragment = (WebViewFragment) get[Support]FragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WebViewFragment.TAG);
webViewFragment.updateWebView(url);
```

You should add `WebViewFragment` in the same `Activity` where your NavigationDrawer is.

Final solution:

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked " + (position+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    WebView webView = (WebView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl(...your url here...)
}
```

Comment: This definitely seems like it will do the trick! Thank you so much. I'll have to look up everything necessary to load the fragment into my mainactivity to fill the space beneath my toolbar when I am able to get back to my desktop, because honestly I have no idea how to do that either at this point. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Oh, just noticed you said I should add `WebViewFragment` to the same activity that my Navigation Drawer is in. Do you mean my MainActivity where the Navigation Drawer is rendered? Or the class the navigation drawer is contained in which is `NavigationDrawerFragment`?

Comment: `MainActivity` where the Navigation Drawer is rendered. In addition you can have a look at Navigation Drawer tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html . In this training instead of finding fragments they create new one (with new data) and replace previous. This is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I'll have to look into that, though I will definitely start with your first bit of advice so I don't have to completely rewrite my Navigation Drawer if not necessary. Once I get this all sorted out I just need to figure out how to have the `RecyclerView` item that corresponds to the current page highlighted, highlight drawer items on click, and then I think I'll be done and happy with the results.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this in my MainActivity per your advice. Mostly null pointer exceptions and a handful of other problems. I hate to ask, but is there any chance you could take a look at my MainActivity and tell me what needs to go where? No worries if you're unable to.

https://gist.github.com/zajrik/25cea982a73bd77f9320

Comment: Where do you handle navigation drawer item click? Please post your NavigationDrawerFragment source code and MainActivity layout xml.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zajrik/32a458f2efc88eb8a8b4

My navigation drawer item clicks are handled by my NavAdapter class, which I've included here, along with activity_main.xml and NavigationDrawerFragment. I am however able to move click handling to NavigationDrawerFragment itself, though I don't know how much difference that will make in terms of accomplishing this goal.

Comment: I edited yout gist. Here you can find the easiest solution without using WebViewFragment: https://gist.github.com/ziem/b00b0a8810c303ab2068#file-navigationdrawerfragment-java (look at line 137 in NavigationDrawerFragment). If you want to use a fragment your code needs a of rewriting ;).

Comment: Oh god, I can't believe how simple that was. I feel like such a goober for not realizing I just needed to findView on the WebView to access it from other places. That never came up, or I overlooked it at least, in all my googling attempts. Thank you so much. I'll test this out and report back

Comment: oh yes, this is definitely working. I feel ridiculous for only needing to add 2 lines of code, but learning isn't without trial and error. Just took help from someone else to overcome those trials and errors. Thank you again. :D